# Would seem versus seem

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs, subjects, will-would

Is it redundant the use of "would" in the sentence below?

> The reduction in blood pressure induced by long-term CR **would seem to involve** positive systemic and cellular adaptations.

Can I just write:

> The reduction in blood pressure induced by long-term CR **seems to involve** positive systemic and cellular adaptations.

?

Comment: You *could* say "would" is "redundant" here. OR you could say it "underlines, emphasises" the speaker / writer's ***hesitancy*** in making his assertion (that's to say, he's ***hedging*** his statements). If he was completely sure of his ground, ***and*** wanted to unambiguously convey that certainty, he could have said *The reduction **involves** positive adaptations* (no "weaselly" words like *would* and *seem*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you might be being presumptive on the meaning of seem in this instance.

Comment: @Brad: It seems we'll just have to agree to differ! I have no idea whether in OP's *specific* example, the speaker/writer is 100% certain of the assertion being made or not (OP hasn't told us). But as a general principle, we often ***do*** say things like *That seems unlikely* when what we actually mean is *That **is** unlikely*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes in general I would agree with you totally, I just feel that in this case that without the use of appears to be (seem) Then the meaning of the sentence becomes a little illogical. Although I think the choice of the word seems is a bad one as it leads to ambiguity. With his use of seems you could possibly be correct if he, the author had used  "appears to", as I suspect he meant to imply, then the ambiguity would not have arisen.

Comment: @Brad: Well, I wouldn't want to overstate my case. Obviously *X **seems to be** true* is often used *literally* (although we don't ***know*** that X is true, the available evidence ***suggests*** it is). And in today's multivalent world, it's hard to actually be certain of *anything*. For all I know, I myself might be a [Boltzmann brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain) that only popped into existence for a millisecond (complete with memories of an entirely fictitious past! :)

Answer (score 0):

Cellular adaptation is the ability of cells to respond to various types of stimuli and adverse environmental changes.

---

**Would seem vs seem,** Although seem and would can be used in a similar fashion and in which case using them both would not be necessary.  In this case ***I believe It is necessary to use both*** as they are used in differing contexts. I believe in this sentence seem is not used in the normal way of alluding to uncertainty but is in fact used to leads us to the suspicion that ***we may possibly have what appears to be*** positive systemic and cellular adaptations.

***Therefore to remove either would or seem, alters the sentence with a significant negative affect.***

*The reduction in blood pressure induced by long-term CR would*

> possibly

> give the effect of being/appears to be

*to involve positive systemic and cellular adaptations.*

---

seem; verb; to give the effect of being; to be judged to be:[C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seem)

appear verb (SEEM) Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appear)

> Things aren't always what they appear to be.

would modal verb (POSSIBILITY); used to refer to a situation that you can imagine happening: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would)